# Does git-flow work together with git-svn

Tags: git-svn, git-flow

As I'm currently bound to a subversion repository, but using git-svn fine, I was wondering if this setup could also be used together with git-flow?
What benefits would git-flow bring? What drawbacks or issues would arise?

Answer (score 2):

When using git-svn, it is best to:

- minimize the number of branches you have to sync back to the svn repo
- don't count on seeing merges between branches done in git published back in svn: they won't appear. Only commit made on the git branch(es) that you dcommit to svn will be there.

And that is the issue, because [git-flow (a *branching* model)](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is great at creating branches for representing the application development life cycle (feature, hotfix, prod branches...), which might be a drag to sync back to svn (usually, git-svn is about keeping in sync *one* branch, just for the legacy SVN repo to keep up with the latests from the git repo).